# Flutter deep link parameter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, deep-linking

I need to open a deep link in my Android app, like `uniqueName://post/detail/1` in the router but it always removes the first part of the link: (`post`) and delegates only the rest: `/detail/1` instead of `/post/detail/1`

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<intent-filter android:priority="1">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="uniqueName"/>
</intent-filter>
```

onGenerateRoute:

```
  Route? onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    print('Change main route to: ${settings.name}');// prints /detail/1
}
```

Test:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW 
                   -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE
                   -d "uniqueName://post/detail/1"
```

Comment: Did you happen to ever find a solution to this?